# OperationalError: create_superuser doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to make a custom user model for my app named **Bookjang**.

When I typed:

```
> python manage.py createsuperuser
```

The following error was raised:

```
> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: Bookjang_user.rank
```

Here is my custom user manager class code:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True
    
    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
    
    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('user_type', 'Manager')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
    
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

And my custom user model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('reader', 'Reader'),  # 독자
        ('author', 'Author'),  # 저자
        ('publisher', 'Publisher'),  # 출판사
        ('manager', 'Manager'),
    )
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    exp = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    user_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default=USER_TYPE_CHOICES[0]
    )
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = UserManager()
```

I already checked the migrations and here it is:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='User',
    fields=[
        ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
        ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
        ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
        ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)),
        ('rank', models.IntegerField(default=1)),
        ('exp', models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[django.core.validators.MinValueValidator(0), django.core.validators.MaxValueValidator(100)])),
        ('user_type', models.CharField(choices=[('reader', 'Reader'), ('author', 'Author'), ('publisher', 'Publisher'), ('manager', 'Manager')], default=('reader', 'Reader'), max_length=10)),
        ('created_date', models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)),
        ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
        ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
        ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
    ],
    options={
        'abstract': False,
    },
    managers=[
        ('objects', Bookjang.models.UserManager()),
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it.

The problem was that I only delete migrations folder not db.sqlite3.

After I deleted both and type command again, it solved perfectly.